# Why isn't it good non-compile scripting languages to use for intensive calculations?

Tags: javascript, compiler-construction

I was reading a ebook about web technologies and I found this.

> JavaScript is a language in its own right (theoretically it isn't tied
>   to web development), it's supported by most web clients under any
>   platform, and it has some object-oriented capabilities. JavaScript is
>   not a compiled language so it's not suited for intensive calculations
>   or writing device drivers and it must arrive in one piece at the
>   client browser to be interpreted so it is not secure either, but it
>   does a good job when used in web pages.

Here my problem is why we can't use JavaScript for process intensive calculations? It doesn't describe in the book. However, I have use JavaScript for mobile applications too, In some we have done very large calculation. How non-compile languages effect on this?

Comment: Your idea of "large calculations" is very small compared to what a scientist would do.

Comment: "theoretically"? I must have imagined all the command line tools I built with it then.

Comment: silly book. most (if not all) modern browsers _do_ compile javascript to native machine code before executing. also, every other code won't work properly too if parts are missing, so the second point is kind of senseless, too. i strongly recomment looking for another book...

Comment: Thanks for the comments, yes I read packet publishing PHP and Ajax responsive web development book, Name is given to avoid above content for newbies like me.

Comment: The security point is a complete strawman. Doesn't matter what langauge or whether it's compiled if you want "me" to run it on my machine. Make that decision, it can't be made secure from me. Even if that was possible, only the ignorant would run it, because they would n't be secure from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two parts to this. 
In a non-compiled language, you have to take a hit to compile or interpret it. Optimisation can reduce the cost of that, ie cache the result of the compilation, though of course that introduces complexity and uses up memory. 
The other side is after a program is compiled, the result can be tweaked and specifically optimised for a particular purpose.

You have to consider the context though, one calculation to isolate a particular Calibi-Yau space was estimated to need 4 years to complete on the best super computer available at the time. So your definition of big and the guy who wrote the article might not be comparable. Course they could be one of those micro-optimisation types...

With modern compiler/interpreters and the most optimised code you can write, has to be a real edge case for this to be significant, and pre-compiled code is pretty much a given in those scenarios.

Comment: what do you mean by "The other side is after a program is compiled, the result can be tweaked and specifically optimised for a particular purpose." ? you say the result can be tweaked. which is not clear. can you explain little bit?

Comment: Once the compiler has compiled, e.g produced an exe. If you know enough or you have the tools, you can optimise at the machine code level, for a particular os, even hardware. Modern compilers are very good, but they still go for a general purpose solution.